# How to parse video thumbnail from Brightcove Video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, brightcove

How to parse video thumbnail from Brightcove Video?
`<x:out select="$item/description" escapeXml="false" />`

Currently I am getting thumbnail inside description.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your data from the [media api](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/#Video_Read) the thumbnail is given as the [thumbnailURL](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/media-api-objects-reference#Video) property.

Comment: What will be the statement to pull it?

Answer (score 0):

As misterben has pointed out, try using the media API. You can use any number of calls (like find_video_by_id) along with the video_fields param to include the thumbnailURL with your response.